# Having Trouble Understanding Javascript Methods

Tags: javascript, function, methods

This is my current assignment :

1. Add a method that will increase the value of one of the numeric properties.
2. Add a method that will decrease the value of the same numeric property.
3. Create a for loop after creating an instance of the character. The loop will iterate 100 times.
4. Inside the loop call one of the methods based on a random number from zero to 3. Using a switch statement, if the value is 0 then call the method that losses; 1 don’t call anything; 2 call the method that gains.

Here is my current coding. I know I'm doing something wrong. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong with the switch statement.

```
 var BR = "<br />";

function person(name, sandwiches) {
this.name = name;
this.sandwiches = sandwiches;


function jump() {
    var text = " leaps over an obstacle.";
    return fname + text;
    }

function run() {
    var text = " runs as fast as they can";
    return fname + text;
    }

function dodge() {
    var attack = math.random();
    var att = math.round(attack);
    var defense = math.random();
    var def = math.round(defense);
    if(att > def) {
        return "You missed";
    }
    else {
        return "You dodged";
    }
}

function date() {
    var today = new Date();
    return today.toDateString();
}

function shout() {
    var word = "Oh no";
    return word.toUpperCase();
}

this.addSandwich = function (sandwiches) {
    sandwiches = sandwiches + 1;
    return sandwiches;
};

this.loseSandwich = function (sandwiches) {
    sandwiches = sandwiches - 1;
    return sandwiches;
};


}

    var character = new person("Jerry", 1);

    for(i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

        switch(random) {
            case 0:
                character.loseSandwich(character.sandwiches);
                console.log(sandwiches);
                break;

            case 1:
                break;

            case 2:
                character.addSandwich(character.sandwiches);
                break;
        }
    }

    document.write("Name: " + character.name + BR);
    document.write("Sandwiches: " + character.sandwiches + BR);
```

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong?  Are you getting a javascript error?  Not the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) is not what you want.

You want something like Math.random() % 3 to get 0, 1, or 2 every single time

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar.  Also to OP, your console.log(sandwhiches) is going to fail.  Use console.log(character.sandwhiches).  Also, I would avoid using document.write().  I know this is just an assignment, but its good practice just to avoid it altogether.

Comment: Why do you think he should use modulus instead? random produces a number 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive), so any number it generates % 3 will always equal the random number itself. For example 0.123 % 3 = 0.123

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but it is at least one of them;

In a few places you have a lowercase `math`, for example:

```
function dodge() {
    var attack = math.random();
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive, and it should be `Math.random()` not `math.random()`

---

Another issue is that these functions:

```
this.addSandwich = function (sandwiches) {
    sandwiches = sandwiches + 1;
    return sandwiches;
};
```

do not change the number of sandwiches. You get in a value of sandwiches, add or subtract 1, then return that changed number, but never use the returned result.
You are only changing the value of the variable that was passed in, not changing the number of sandwiches on the instance of the person.

Note that `this.sandwiches` (the variable on the instance of a `person`) is not the same variable as `sandwiches` (the function argument)

I dont think there is any reason to pass the number of sandwiches into those functions, and they could just do:

```
this.addSandwich = function () {
    this.sandwiches = this.sandwiches + 1;
};
```

or more simply:

```
this.addSandwich = function () {
    this.sandwiches++;
};
```

---

Another problem here:

```
            character.loseSandwich(character.sandwiches);
            console.log(sandwiches);
```

The `console.log` statement is trying to log `sandwiches` but that is not a variable at that point. You probably wanted `console.log(character.sandwiches);` However this wouldn't cause an exception, it would just always log `undefined`.